# How to extract all the users in a OU in Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

In our AD, we have an OU which has approx 2500 user accounts. We want to extract the list of users in a csv, following command I tried but the results are limited to 2000 accounts only.

`Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=TestOU,DC=test,DC=com" -Properties * -ResultSetSize 20000 -ResultpageSize 20000 | Select-Object name, DisplayName, DistinguishedName, GivenName, Surname, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, Description, HomeDirectory, gidNumber, Enabled, @{Name="MemberOf";Expression={$_.MemberOf | ForEach-Object{(Get-ADGroup -Identity $_).Name + ";"}}},AccountExpirationDate,@{n='Path';e={$_.DistinguishedName -replace '^.+?,(CN|OU.+)','$1'}} | export-csv -path E:\AllUserExport.csv -NoTypeInformation`

How to extract all the users accounts?

Comment: The command seems okay. Perhaps this is a server side setting.

Comment: Could you try using `-ResultSize unlimited` Also what exact error are you getting?

Comment: There are no errors presented. The exported csv contains 2000 records instead of 2500. Already tried with resultsetsize and pagesize

Comment: How did you determine that the OU has 2500 user accounts? And have you tried without using `-ResultSetSize` and `-ResultPageSize`? The defaults should get everything it can.

Comment: [ResultSetSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps): 
Specifies the maximum number of objects to return for an Active Directory Domain Services query. If you want to receive all of the objects, set this parameter to $Null (null value). The default is $Null

Comment: `(Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=TestOU,DC=test,DC=com" | measure-object Count).Count` to see how many objects you actually have.